# How to solve an error with MercadoPago SDK?

Tags: ios, flutter

good morning, I am having a problem when executing "pod install" on ios and flutter, it gives me an error with a MercadoPago SDK, the error it shows me is:

**[!] Error installing MercadoPagoSDK
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios.git /var/folders/y4/6qf0hlld2k36tt90_hrv5g380000gn/T/d20230518-15114-4a4z3g --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 4.32.4

Cloning into '/var/folders/y4/6qf0hlld2k36tt90_hrv5g380000gn/T/d20230518-15114-4a4z3g'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios.git/' not found**

Did that happen to anyone else?

Know if it happened to someone else and how to fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also experiencing this issue. When I open https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios.git in the browser, I receive the following error:

The MercadoPago Developers organization has an IP allow list enabled. Please contact an owner of the organization for details on allowed IP addresses for the account.

It seems that your IP address needs to be added to MercadoPago Developers allow list.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because MercadoPago has restricted access to the [mercadopago/px-ios](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios) repository on GitHub.

More info on [this issue](https://github.com/BlackBoxVision/react-native-mercadopago-px/issues/86)